# What is the code to filter a list in netlogo? Changes in Netlogo 6?

Tags: list, filter, netlogo

The following code given in the dictionary does not work in NetLogo 6:

show filter [ i -> i < 3 ] [1 3 2]

=> [1 2]

The error message is:

ERROR: Nothing named I has been defined.

What I want to do is pathetically simple: count the number of certain items in a list. I thought filtering for the item and then counting the number of that item in the resulting list is a reasonable way of doing it. Other ways? Or how to fix the problem?

THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

I copy/pasted and ran the code you posted in NetLogo 6.1.0, `show filter [ i -> i < 3 ] [1 3 2]`, and I get the result `[1 2]`.

If you're using NetLogo 6.0.0 you will need to put square brackets are the reporter for `filter`, so `show filter [ [i] -> i < 3 ] [1 3 2]`  [The 6.0.0 docs, including `filter`, are still online](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0.0/docs/dictionary.html#filter) if you need them.

You can get the count, then, by doing `length filter [ [i] -> i < 3 ] [ 1 3 2 ]` and get `2` as the result, as expected.  Or you can upgrade to 6.1.0 and do `length filter [ i -> i < 3 ] [ 1 3 2 ]`.

Comment: Jasper, THANKS very much. I did install version 6.1.0. and as you said, it does now work. My older version must have been 6.0.0 and I was not aware of the link that you provided. Good to know that are people like you, willing to help just to be helpful. Thanks again.